# Download all pages linked on a page in a certain region

Tags: backup, wget, download

I would like to download my [users activity page of this Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all) with `wget` and all pages that are linked in the activity list.

I tried

```
wget -m -l 2
```

which should mirror the site recursively but only max one level in recursion depth, but that is not a good solution. especially the stylesheet is not downloaded correctly.

Is there a solution that also downloads all needed CSS and images and keeps links between those questions locally intact? A perfect solution would be if on those downloaded questions were shown with everything intact, i.e. comments, etc.

related:

- [How do I backup my Stackexchange favorites for offline use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158546/how-do-i-backup-my-stackexchange-favorites-for-offline-use)
- [Mirror all Stack Exchange pages where you were active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292850/188615)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with `httrack` will do what you want.

```
$ httrack \
    'http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all' \
    -* +*question* -r2
```

This won't proceed past the first page of pagination of that page. You could likely modify it so that it could. It could also be looped through the pagination pages too.

The above downloads 2 levels (`-r2`) and ignores all pages that do not include the path `*question*`.

#### Commentary on this approach

With this type of download you'll likely have to run a more complex command a couple of times to determine that you've gotten everything that's required to keep the pages locally. Not to worry though, you can keep running `httrack` in the same directory and it will detect that its already download various pieces and either skip them, or update them where appropriate.

**NOTE:** This is a by-product of the approach were using, where we've explicitly excluded everything with the `-*`, and then selectively added things back in with a `+...`. You could always cast the net wider and tell `httrack` to download more, but then you'll be pulling in a lot more data too.

#### Iterating the download

For example, here I'm running it multiple times as I identify other files that I want to have it pull down.

*run #1*

```
$ httrack \
    'http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all' \
    -* +*question* +*sstatic.net* -r2 

There is an index.html and a hts-cache folder in the directory 
A site may have been mirrored here, that could mean that you want to update it
Be sure parameters are ok

Press <Y><Enter> to confirm, <N><Enter> to abort
Y
Mirror launched on Fri, 07 Nov 2014 14:01:35 by HTTrack Website Copier/3.48-19 [XR&CO'2014]
mirroring http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all -* +*question* +*sstatic.net* with the wizard help..
Done.: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163334/connecting-to-irc-and-log-all-conversations (62646 bytes) - OK
Thanks for using HTTrack!
```

*run #2*

```
$ httrack \
    'http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all' \
    -* +*question* +*sstatic.net* +*googleapis* -r2 

There is an index.html and a hts-cache folder in the directory 
A site may have been mirrored here, that could mean that you want to update it
Be sure parameters are ok

Press <Y><Enter> to confirm, <N><Enter> to abort
Y
Mirror launched on Fri, 07 Nov 2014 14:03:05 by HTTrack Website Copier/3.48-19 [XR&CO'2014]
mirroring http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=all -* +*question* +*sstatic.net* +*googleapis* with the wizard help..
Done.: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163334/connecting-to-irc-and-log-all-conversations (62646 bytes) - OK
Thanks for using HTTrack!
```

In the above I identified that Stack Exchange makes use of GoogleAPI's so I needed to add that into the filter chain so that `httrack` knows to download files from that site as well.

I generally either use `grep` to look through the files to make sure I have everything, or I use my web browser's "view source" feature to see what URLs are still coming from other sites, vs. my local system.

**NOTE:** You can open the resulting downloads in Chrome, using the `file:///path/to/httrack/download/index.html`, and navigate the contents.

#### References

- [Httrack Users Guide](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)

Comment: @rubo77 - try what I showed. It downloaded the first page just fine and I could navigate it locally.

Comment: Will try when iam out of bed later ☺

Comment: @rubo77 - ha, I'm going to bed now. I'm pretty confident that httrack can do the pagination as well, the URL you provided has your activity spread across multiple pages, i.e. the 1,2,3,...Last bit at the bottom.

Comment: httrack works just great! Only one problem I couldn't solve: [Mirroring stackexchange including external images](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166578/mirror-stackexchange-including-external-immages)

Comment: @rubo77 - please don't use exclamation points, simply pointing this out is sufficient. You need to add in additional pathing is all, since the approach I specified excludes everything (`-*`) and then adds paths back in (`+...`). So add a rule such as `+*.css`, etc. Also the approach I'm showing is a model. You'll have to play with it to get exactly the results you're after, but it definitely works, as I've used it for a variety of projects over the years to achieve similar results.

Comment: @rubo77 - also please do read the references that I link to. For example, the guide for httrack covers how to download based on mime types here: http://httrack.kauler.com/help/Filters. You can tell `httrack` to download CSS mime types: `+mime:text/css`.

Comment: The documentation is really hard to understand, cause it explains EVERYTHING. Hard to find a solution for a simple problem. I now tried `httrack "$SITE/$USERNAME/?tab=activity&sort=all&page=$c" -* "+*/questions/*"  +*sstatic.net* +*googleapis* +*gravatar* +*imgur.com* +mime:text/css -r2` but still it doesn download gravatars and images from imgur.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software called `black widow` (on Windows): it has a GUI to download parts of websites to the hardrive.

[Black Widow](http://softbytelabs.com/wp/blackwidow/)