# Mirroring stackexchange including external images

Tags: shell-script, httrack

This script will create a mirror folder with all my activity pages saved for offline reading including all affected questions

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=rubo77
MAXDEPTH=2 # increase this if you want to backup more of your history
USERID=1047481

mkdir -p mirror_$USERNAME
cd mirror_$USERNAME/
TEMP=/tmp/tmp.stackexchange_export
wget http://stackexchange.com/users/$USERID/$USERNAME?tab=accounts -q -O $TEMP
for SITE in $(grep account-icon $TEMP -A 4 | grep users | sed -r 's/.*(http[^"]*)".*/\1/g'); do
    echo '### ' $SITE ' ###'
    for c in $(seq 1 2); do
        DIR=$(echo $SITE|tr / _|sed s/^http:__//)$c
        mkdir -p $DIR
        cd $DIR
        httrack "$SITE$USERNAME/?tab=activity&sort=all&page=$c" \
                -* "+*/questions/*" +*sstatic.net* +*googleapis* \
                +*gravatar* +*imgur.com* +mime:text/css -r2 -N1
        cd ../
    done
done
```

But how can I include external images like avatars and included images from imgur?

Comment: `wget -p` should help

Comment: I tried `wget -p -r -l 2 http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/rubo77?tab=activity
` but that  doesn't seem to download the css either and now my IP address is blocked at stackexchange ;)

Comment: That won't help with your script, but for a single Q/A with lots of images etc., you could create a pdf with [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, beware the [scraping etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow), or you'll [get blocked/throttled](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

If you're into programming, you might consider using [stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) instead, for example expanding on one of the [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) like [stackprinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite). See this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65750/offline-copy-of-my-stackoverflow-questions) and [related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73139/application-to-read-stack-overflow-off-line) for more ways to get to data and apps that do it.

But I'm guessing from your question that you'd be served best by just simply using any offline Atom/RSS reader to subscribe to [changes on your account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/20661)

**EDIT1**: If you just want the same site to be available when you're offline, perhaps it is best to just use some caching HTTP proxy. I'd had good experiences with [wwwoffle](http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/) in the past for example (it never expired anything unless you told it manually, and would even remember which links you clicked that weren't available offline so would fetch them next time you went online), but almost any caching proxy will do if you configure it correctly (especially disk limit/expire times). If you don't want to cache whole internet (as you usually do not for such cases), you need to either configure proxy to cache only some URLs, or do it in web browser itself (via plugins like [foxyproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) or using simple [.pac file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). That will work nicely and transparently, requires no programming, and will even reduce load at the SE sites (instead of hammering them with lots of request in short time as in screen scraping example)

If you still insist on using screen scraping, it will work, but you will have to have to carefully limit it to only fetch things you need and no more (and continue updating script as sites change), and add delays between URL retrievals to prevent being blocked, and reuse existing cached content if it hasn't changed (`wget --mirror` etc). But it most probably will require some programming to get finer nuances (even if in shell with sed/awk).

Please in such cases always setup custom user-agent (like `--user-agent="RuboScraper-1.1"`) so when script does get blocked it does not block rest of the non-abusive **wget**s in the world. And when you do make it work, put it up on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) and link from here to it, so other users won't have to reinvent to wheel and do all the bumping into the walls.

Comment: Did not know stackprinter; really useful, thanks!

Comment: I am not so into programming an api for this. All I want to achieve is to have an offline copy of all my activities in all stackexchange sites, that I can browse through offline including working links to other questions and all images

Comment: I think `wwwoffle` is outdated and replaced by `polipo`, here is a [howto use polipo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Polipo)